# Use of Dto in Retrofit Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, dto

What is the use of DTO (Data Access Object) when using Retrofit ?

It is used to Convert JSON Response from API to data class in Kotlin.

But in the below code, I directly make API Call & it will automatically be parsed into my Actual Business Data Class "MemeList".

And it is working fine.

```
@GET("{count}")
suspend fun getMemeList(
    @Path("count") count: Int = 50,
): MemeList
```

So, I wonder what is the use of DTO, & the overhead work which come with them.
(make dtos, convert dto to Business Class)

Comment: What do you mean by directly parsed into the Business data class, how are you doing that?

Comment: Yes, you can do like that. But its not the proper way to do Api calling if you use proper data class then you will use the pre-defined method of data class at the time of transferring object and add logic over the complete response